# please tell me the correct use of the word boredom in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

How do I use boredom in a sentence? For example:

> He danced to kill his boredom.

I want to know the correct sentence in that same pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, your sentence is fine.

Idiomatically, I'm not sure that *kill* is a word that I would use with *boredom*, though it's perfectly understandable. I would probably say *get rid of* or *drive away*.

Why would I not use *kill*? I think it's because *boredom* is something so passive - it's sort of dead already, and taking it away is making something more lively.

In a more literary register, I might say *assuage*.

Comment: I would use "relieve" over assuage, but otherwise I agree with your answer.